# Will Apple approve there UIButtons?

Tags: ios, uibutton

This question was probably asked before in different version, but I couldn't find one that specific answer it.
I know the Apple HIG says that UIButtons show have a size of 44x44 points.

Can I make a UIButton of size (for example) 100x40? where the width is wider and the hight is shorter than 44 ?

I think Instagram has one of these buttons.

Thanks,
Oded.

Answer (score 1):

44x44 points is the minimum suggested area for an active element because with your finger in the average case is the minimum area that you can touch... but the apple review guide lines doesn't say anything about that, you can use smaller element... will be only more difficult for the user to tap... my apps have smaller button than 44x44p also

Answer (score 1):

Buttons can be smaller, but if you start making the distance between the buttons smaller, the chance of tapping the wrong button increases. 44 points is a safe distance.

In case of doubt, test to see if the button can still be tapped easilly

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides their own apps with buttons smaller than 44x44 and some of the standard interfaces have them too. It's more of a guideline than a rule.